# Bad request 400 returns from API Patch method

Tags: c#, postman, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi, http-patch

I'm using .net core web api. in my API controller class have `PATCH` method as follows,

```
[HttpPatch("updateMessageTemplate/{templateId}")]
public IActionResult UpdateMessageTemplate([FromHeader] int tenantId, int templateId,[FromBody] testClass msg)
{
    try
    {
        //Some implementation is here
        return Accepted();
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

`testClass` as follows,

```
public class testClass
{
    public string body { get; set; }
}
```

I called the API from postman and its returns 400 BadRequest.

[image]
[image]

I placed the breakpoint in Controller method, but its not hitting. after I removed the `[FromBody] testClass msg` from the method parameter breakpoin hit without return `400` . why its returns 400 when I use `[FromBody] testClass msg` ? And how can I call this controller method from the HTTP Client ?.

I tried this, its also returns 400 BadRequest

```
string serviceUrl = string.Format("{0}/notification/updateMessageTemplate/{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LtApiUrl"], templateID);

string json = "[{\"body\":\"sample text\"}]";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpMethod method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(method, serviceUrl);

StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("tenantId", tenantId.ToString());
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", string.Format("bearer {0}", token));
message.Content = content;

var response = client.SendAsync(message).Result;               
return response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

How can I solve this? please help me. I deleted the previous question and this is my real problem

**Updated:**

I changed the postman request as.

[image]

after that its works. but when I call it through http client code its provides `400 BadRequest`. how to provide JSON body correct way through http client

Comment: Please don't open new questions. Edit your original question.

Comment: @canton7 I deleted it sir, no one care about that question :( I'm really stuck with this. please help me

Comment: I still recommend increasing the logging on the server, and getting it to tell you what's wrong with the request.

Comment: Also try removing bits. Take out the header. Does that make it work? Remove the url param, the body, make it get or post instead of patch. Figure out which bit specifically is causing the problem.

Comment: @canton7 I changed the postman request as https://i.imgur.com/NF1OaNl.png . after that its works. but when I call it through http client code its provides 400 BadRequest . How to pass [FromBody] in correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you use `FromBody`,you need to send request with json instead of form data.You could change your postman like below:

1.change the ContentType to `application/json`:

[image]

2.change the Body to raw and choose the style JSON:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

You need change your json like below:

```
string json = "{\"body\":\"sample text\"}";
```

Comment: yeah I did it and solved it through the POSTMAN. but how can I call it through the http client code(please check my code in question). please help me to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this.

```
[HttpPatch("updateMessageTemplate/{templateId}")]
public IActionResult UpdateMessageTemplate([FromHeader] int tenantId, int templateId, 
[FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<testMsg> msg)
 {
 try
 {
    //Some implementation is here
    return Accepted();
 }
 catch
 {
    return StatusCode(500);
 }
}
```

Comment: Not working. have any proper way to find the real issue by debugging

Comment: I changed the postman request as https://i.imgur.com/NF1OaNl.png . after that its works. but when I call it through http client code its provides 400 BadRequest